# Power Tower and Finite Tetration

Tags: exponentiation, perfect-powers

Let $$\underbrace{a^{a^{.^{.^{.}}}}}_{2020} =2020$$

How can I solve for $a$? Had this been an infinite power tower, I could have used the self-replication. But the finite number of terms (i.e. $2020$ times) makes me think there is another way to solve it, which I currently am not able to think of.

Comment: Although your question is clear, you should use MathJax for typing in the math equations. Coming to your question, you need an intelligent guess. See, $a$ to the power of something is $2020$, so surely $a = 2020^{\frac 1{a^{a^...}}}$  i.e. $a = 2020^{y}$ for some $y$. Try substituting this in.

Comment: I believe are methods for estimation outlined under the [inverse operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Inverse_operations) on the Wikipedia page for tetration. As far as I know, super-roots such as these have no closed-form expression and will need some sort of gradient descent from an initial guess.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon diagonally upwards dots doesn’t seem to be supported.

Comment: @BenjaminWang You can do it via .^{.^{.^{...}}} like so : $2^{2^{2^{.^{.^{.}}}}}$

Comment: I am still not sure how can I guess y for some value of a which itself is a function of a.

Comment: How did you have this problem? Are you sure whether an analytical (or even simi-analytical) solutionfor $a$ exists?

Comment: The solution will be slightly larger than $e^{e^{-1}}$ , the largest positive real number for which the infinite power tower converges. A possible notation  is , by the way , $a\uparrow \uparrow 2020$